Payload CMS Beta - Email Adapter Config Error
Does anyone know if @/payloadcms/email-nodemailer is compatible with payload beta? I am trying to use it but I get this error and don't know how to solve it. Neither nodemailer or resend works for me but I get different import error for each adapter.
email: nodemailerAdapter({
    defaultFromAddress: 'info@acme.com',
    defaultFromName: 'Acme',
    transportOptions: {
      host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.SMTP_USER,
        pass: process.env.SMTP_PASS,
      },
    },
  }),

This is the error I get when adding nodemailerAdapter to config:
Failed to compile

./node_modules/.pnpm/@payloadcms+email-nodemailer@3.0.0-beta.29_payload@3.0.0-beta.109_graphql@16.9.0_monaco-edito_nfaudzqjhluloumofguwvfbbou/node_modules/@payloadcms/email-nodemailer/dist/index.js:2:1
Module not found: Package path ./errors is not exported from package /node_modules/.pnpm/@payloadcms+email-nodemailer@3.0.0-beta.29_payload@3.0.0-beta.109_graphql@16.9.0_monaco-edito_nfaudzqjhluloumofguwvfbbou/node_modules/payload (see exports field in /node_modules/payload/package.json)
  1 | /* eslint-disable no-console */ import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
> 2 | import { InvalidConfiguration } from 'payload/errors';
    | ^
  3 | /**
  4 |  * Creates an email adapter using nodemailer
  5 |  *



Import trace for requested module:
./src/payload.config.ts
./src/app/(payload)/layout.tsxhttps://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Has anyone managed to use emails with payload beta?
